# Rotate Aspect Ratio But Not Image

Tags: google-photos

I'd like to rotate the 4:3 aspect ratio so that the 4 is on the horizontal and the 3 is on the vertical, but the image remains unrotated.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. Aspect Ratio is defined as the width compared to the height of the image, and there is a convention to state it in the order `width:height`. If you wanted to swap them you *have* to rotate the image so that the width becomes the old height and the height becomes the old width. Swapping the order of the ratio to be stated as `height:width` is against convention, and a very unusual thing for most software to allow.

Comment: Do you want to stretch it or crop it? You have to do one or the other.